# Different function starting for methods

Tags: javascript

In Codecademy, a normal function is shown as:

```
var abc = function (xyz) { ...
```

However, whenever there is an example of a method, this is used:

```
function abc (xyz) { ...
```

I have seen other explanations on which to use, but I am still unclear and this seems to be how the Codecademy course does it.

Is this a general rule for which way to define a function/method?

Here is an extract from Codecademy:

Recall that we can add methods (i.e., functions associated with objects) to a constructor:

```
function someObject() {
this.someMethod = function() {
};
}
```

Comment: Neither one of the above is sufficient for a method definition so you must not be showing all of the code for a method definition.  Please show what you're asking about in a fuller context.  For example, if you're doing a static object definition that is assigned to a prototype, then you would use this style: `obj.prototype = { methodName: function() {}}`.  If you were adding a method onto an existing prototype, you would use `obj.prototype.methodName = function() {};`.  It's not a matter of right or wrong, but which fits the situation.

Comment: Here is an example from the current section I am on: Recall that we can add methods (i.e., functions associated with objects) to a constructor: function someObject() { this.someMethod = function() {}; }   (Sorry if it's unclear with the spacing).

Comment: Please use the edit link to edit your original post to show the fuller context.  Code in comments is not as easy to read and you want to clarify your question for everyone who reads it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm relatively new here, added it to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to use for methods is generally selected based on the type of syntax that is more apporopriate to the coding situation.

For example, if you are adding a method to an existing object or prototype, then you can really only use the assignment method:

```
// adding a method to an existing prototype
MyConstructor.prototype.myMethod = function() {};

// adding a method to an existing object
myObj.myMethod = function() {};
```

Whereas, if your assigning a whole new object to a prototype, you would use something like this:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = {
    myMethod1: function() {},
    myMethod2: function() {}
};
```

No syntax here is more right or wrong, but rather more appropriate to how you choose to define things and structure your code.

Comment: Are the first two examples basically constructor notation, whilst the second block shows an example of literal notation with methods? And therefore is this the difference between functions and methods; methods are for objects and are entered as shown with constructor/literal notation?

Comment: @Hamish - A method is just a function that is assigned as a property of an object and thus is callable as a property of the object.  Methods can be assigned directly to the object or on the object's prototype.  There is no other difference between a method and a function.